# Is a Gumpe the same as a plunge pool or stream pool?

Tags: rivers

In river morphology, a [plunge pool](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plunge_pool) is a (small) lake formed at the bottom of a waterfall.

In German, there exists the word [*Gumpe*](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumpe), apparently from Bavarian.  From the German language Wikipedia, a *Gumpe* is a *überwiegend beckenartige Strudeltopfe, die von Sturzbächen in den felsigen Untergrund eines Bachbetts erodiert werden*, which may be translated as *predominantly basin-like [swirl pot] eroded by torrents into the rocky bedrock of a streambed* (I'm not sure how to translate *Strudeltopf*).  The sources cited by Wikipedia are from 1887 and 1935.

The description of *Gumpe* seems quite similar to the description of a *plunge pool*, but the German language Wikipedia article on *Gumpe* has only one interlanguage link, to a Bavarian entry.  The English language Wikipedia article on *plunge pool* has no interlanguage link to German.

Is a *Gumpe* the same as a *plunge pool* or is there a difference?  Is a *Gumpe* a specific type of *plunge pool*, or something quite different?

Comment: Interestingly, Google Translate, for what it is worth, does not translate *Gumpe* into English, but its translation of plunge pool in English is *Tauchbecken* in German. I'm not aware of different types of plunge pools

Comment: @Fred *Tauchbecken* seems to be used for swimming pools one can plunge in, not for small lakes formed at the bottom of a waterfall...

Comment: It seems to be a special form of [Giant's kettles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Giant%27s_kettle).

Comment: @Erik Are you sure?  My colleague uses *Gumpe* for stream pools on Corsica, which I don't think are glacial.  But it's possible he's using it wrongly.